# The IDLE editor in Python will not run my code when I do not save it

Tags: python, python-idle

[image]I have written code in a New file window in IDLE.

When I run the code there is no output.
Instead a dialog box appears showing a window accessing Python Folder 37-32.

When i closed the dialog box and the file I tried to create a new simple code below but I when I ran the code I got the same Dialog box.

What is wrong?

```
sum = 2+3 print(sum)
```

I have attached a screenshot showing the code and the dialog box that appears when the Module is run

Comment: Insufficient details in the question. Code? Screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can execute your code, your first need to save the file. Thats the dialog box that popped up.

Comment: Also, do not close the dialog box, choose a save location and click save.

Comment: Thanks Lads, I saved the file in the Scripts folder. I named it "practice". I then tried to open it by using open('practice') but i get an error saying no such file or directory. why is this?

Comment: IDLE is just a text editor. It can't execute any code on it's own. It first needs to save the file. That is where the dialog box is for. Then you can execute your code with IDLE's run function. It basically says to python, hey, please run this code. So run the exact code as you made in the question. Than IDLE will say to Python to execute your code. In the same folder where the file is saved, a new file should pop up with the name hello.txt, as you coded yourself.

Comment: Ok, Im after opening the file named practice and I changed its code to to this open('new','w+'). I then selected run. I got this answer  RESTART: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\practice.py. I checked in the Scripts folder and  no file named "new" has been created. why is this?

Comment: should I  ask a new question?

Comment: No, replace 'w+', to 'w' in your open statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should have seen a popup box like below.  Did you?  Is is unclear?

```
Save Before Run or Check
?  Source Must Be Saved
    OK to Save?
  [OK]    [Cancel]
```

One reason to require saving is that exception tracebacks refer to the file and line of lines that lead to the exception.

If you had saved, `sum = 2+3 print(sum)` would be a SyntaxError.

You can run single statements in Shell without saving.

The RESTART lines says that the shell re-initialized the environment for executing your code.

You should normally not save your code buried in the installation Scripts directory. Better to make a directory in your user directory, for instance, C:/Users/yourname/py/.

Yes, one should usually open a new question for unrelated questions.  But without access to your machine, it is hard to know what happened with 'new'.  It may be that IDLE could create a file under `.../appdate/.../Scripts/`, but your code cannot.  If the open call did not raise and exception, it was likely created somewhere.  Until you are more experienced, better to use absolute paths, such as `C:/Users/yourname/py/new.txt`.